# Multi-node hadoop cluster installation

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera

Sorry if my question appears to be naïve. We are planning to use CDH 5.3.0 or 5.4.0. We want to implement a multi-node cluster.

The example multi-node installations that I have seen/read on different blogs/resources have master and slaves on different hosts.

However, we are restrained by the number of hosts. We have only 2 powerful hosts ( 32 cores 400+ GB RAM), so if we decide to have master on one and slave on other, we will end up with only one slave. My questions are :

1. Is it possible to have master and slave on the same hosts?
2. Can I have more than one slave node on a single host.
3. Also does one need to pay to use Cloudera Manager or it is open-source like the rest of the components.

If you can point me in the direction of some resource which would help me understand above scenarios it would be helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

V

Answer (score 1):

old question but no and wrong answer:

1. yes, it is possible to install Master & Worker services on a single host.
   e.g. HDFS (NameNode and Datanode). You can even install a full cloudera or Hortonworks installation with ALL services on a single host if it is powerfull enough, but i would only recommend it for POC or testcases.
2. If you use cloudera or hortonworks without virtualization it is not possible to run multiple instances of the SAME worker services e.g. datanode on the same host. 1 Host 1 worker instance. everything else would not make sense.
3. Cloudera is a package of multiple open source projekt (Hadoop,Spark....) and other closed source parts like cloudera manager and other enterprise closed source features. But everything you need is free even for commercial use with the community licence. 
   Right now (2017): only cloudera navigator is the big feature which is not part of the community edition

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can configure namenode and datanode both on a single node.
2. You cannot have more than two datanodes on a single machine.
3. Cloudera is open-source hadoop distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your second point..did you mean I can have only one slave node on a single machine?

Comment: Yes you can have only one datanode running on a single machine.